# CEFSharp (Chromium Embedded Framework) - Wonderware

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, activex, wonderware

As you may know, the .net controls (webBrowser-control) and activeX control (webBrowser-control) can be finicky to say the least. I am looking to utilize the CEFSharp (Chromium Embedded Framework) but with Wonderware - InTouch. Does any one have experience with this and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi man, did you tried? i had no idea about this framework, i will for sure try to install it in our dev environment and see how it works. Have you tried? any experiences you would like to share?